# Truncating out higher order polynomials in series of fractions

Tags: polynomials

I have taken sequential partial derivatives of a two variable polynomial fraction, resulting in a very long series of polynomials of form:

```
C*x^i*y^j/(some product series of (1-x^k*y)^n)
```

What I wish to do is a series of basic truncations. First, I eliminate all polynomials that have `x^i*y^j` with `i` or `j > 4` in the numerator. I keep looking over the documentation and StackExchange and cannot find anything that works for me.

I am open to suggestions.

Edit: Thus far, I have merely sorted the long series, and picked out the valid fractions starting from the bottom. What is the solution that uses Mathematica functions?

Comment: Without a complete, even if simpler, example to work with, perhaps this is will work: `Replace[expr, term_ /; MemberQ[Numerator[term], (x | y)^i_ /; i > 4] -> 0, 1]`??  It assumes the expression for your rational function has been expanded in the way you describe.  Please clarify whether this is right or wrong.

Comment: `PolynomialReduce` is a good function for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I post this as a way to handle polynomials that could be modified to suit your needs:

```
func[exp_, vars_, pattern_] := 
 FromCoefficientRules[
  Cases[CoefficientRules[exp, vars], HoldPattern[pattern]], vars]
```

Example:

```
expr = (1 - x^2 y)^10;
Column[{Expand@expr, func[expr, {x, y}, Rule[{_?(# > 4 &), _}, _]]}, 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]